# Ideas or algorithms when programming an NAT

Tags: python, sockets, networking, nat

I'm working on a Python tunneling project using TUNTAP.  The data received on a TUNTAP interface contains the original IP packet including all headers.  I can do one of two things.

On the incoming side I am listening with Twisted.  On the outgoing side I will have a raw socket which dumps the IP packet.  Before dumping the packet the program swaps the source address with that of the server.  It also recomputes the TCP and UDP checksums.  It also swaps the ports using one of the following methods.  This information is tracked in the NAT table

1) Use a single port per user such as

```
 US.ER.01.IP:10000 ----> SE.RV.ER.IP:3000 ----> facebook.com:80
 US.ER.01.IP:10001 ----> SE.RV.ER.IP:3000 ----> facebook.com:80
 US.ER.02.IP:3000 ----> SE.RV.ER.IP:3001 ----> facebook.com:80
```

Could this cause issues if the second with user's 1s simultaneous requests for facebook?  How would the system know how to route facebook's reply.  It is incoming on port 3000 so it belongs to user1 but does it get mapped back to 10000 or 10001?

2) Use a unique port for each connection such as

```
 US.ER.01.IP:10000 ----> SE.RV.ER.IP:3000 ----> facebook.com:80
 US.ER.01.IP:10001 ----> SE.RV.ER.IP:3001 ----> facebook.com:80
 US.ER.02.IP:3000 ----> SE.RV.ER.IP:3002 ----> remoteHost.com:22
```

How would I know when to remove entries from the NAT table?  I could see the NAT table filling up very quickly using this method.  The solutions to this are:

```
  I could wit for FIN packets from the server.  This will not work with UDP though.
  I could age the NAT entry on each hit.  I could then run garbage collection 
     every N seconds.  I see this being an issue if garbage collection runs
     and how would a server's delayed response get to the proper host if it gets
     deleted from the table.
```

There is also the issue of reading from a raw socket.  I know how to send on one but would it be possible to receive individual IP packets.  Could the raw socket receive one packet per sock.recieve(65535) call possibly receive more than one IP packet?

Which implementation is best?  Any other tips or things I should be watching out for?

EDITS:

Ok so I have N many clients.  If you misunderstood me the enitre /30 is used
between the client and itself.  It is just an abstraction to make the tunnel
possible.  I also didn't think it mattered but the websocket actaully goes through a "proxy" on the LAN (the IPdata is
simply repackaged into a new websocket, the mappings are unique however).  I did not want to make the explanation so confusing.  I do not see how this changes anything.

```
      Client PC     CLIENT PC              Client PC----->LAN                               INTERNET    
 Client 1: 10.1.1.2 ----> 10.1.1.1 ----> Websocket(IPdata) ----> Browser ---> newWebSocket(IPData) ----> SE.RV.ER.IP
 Client 2: 10.1.1.4 ----> 10.1.1.3 ----> Websocket(IPdata) ----> Browser ---> newWebSocket(IPData) ----> SE.RV.ER.IP
 Client 3: 10.1.1.6 ----> 10.1.1.5 ----> Websocket(IPdata) ----> Browser ---> newWebSocket(IPData) ----> SE.RV.ER.IP
```

Each client set it's default route to be the tunnel endpoint (10.1.1.1 for example).  The client gets the IP datagram, puts it
into a websocket, sends the websocket to a browser on the LAN, which then sends it to the server (or perhaps another proxy).  The inside of the websocket contains
the original IP datagram (with the source of 10.1.1.2 or some other internal IP).

It is important to note that the server recieves a websocket message from the internet CONTAINING the goodes (with the private source address).  How would the python server use this?  Create a new tunnel with itself then dump the packet raw into the tunnel and route appropriately?

Or perhaps I could use a mapping?

How would I be able to "map" a tunnel abstraction over this chain of websockets?  The client does not have a route to the
internet but can reach the "Browser" which can get to the internet.  This seems to be the same case with VPN tunnels.  The
abstraction would be as follows:

```
 Client 1: 10.1.1.2 ----> 10.1.1.1 ----> Websocket(IPdata) ----> Browser ---> newWebSocket(IPData) ----> SE.RV.ER.IP -> Internet
           10.1.2.2------------------------------------------------------------------------------------> 10.1.2.1 ----> Internet
```

If you know any resources to get me on the right track that would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Implementing NAT

You must use a unique port for each connection, not a single port per user, for exactly the reason that you outline in your question: if you don't then you can (and will!) end up with multiple connections using the same 5-tuple (protocol,local-address,local-port,remote-address,remote-port) and you won't be able to disambiguate them.

Moreover, if you want to play nice with some protocols that do NAT traversal then you should try to *not* remap the original source port if possible, that is, only remap it (to a new random port) if it conflicts with an existing connection which you are tracking.

To implement a NAT correctly, you must track the state of each connection.

For TCP this means watching the flags, setting up new state when you see a `SYN`, and tearing down the state when you see `FIN`s from both sides. The state you track must contain at least the original source port and the remapped source port (which might be the same, see above). If you want to support FTP then you will also have to sniff the contents of FTP TCP control connections and rewrite IP addresses contained therein (and this means you will need to track a lot more state because you may sometimes need to enlarge a TCP segment which means you need to start remapping sequence numbers). You should also have a time out associated with each tracked connection so that you get rid of it in case the endpoints disappear without closing the connection properly.

For UDP this means watching the combinations of local and remote port numbers and creating state for each unique combination (of 4-tuple of addresses and ports) that you see. Because UDP is connectionless you have to expire this state information based on a timeout. This timeout will be much shorter than the one you use for TCP (on the order of minutes instead of hours) in order to prevent your state table from getting too large.

For ICMP echo request you should proceed in a manner similar to UDP with the icmp_id playing the role of port number.

For other types of ICMP like destination unreachable you must inspect the ICMP packet to see if it is part of a TCP or UDP connection you are tracking and attempt to translate it back to the original source.

In order to prevent routing loops you should also be decrementing the IP TTL as you forward translated packets.

There are probably some more important bits which I'm forgetting. In short, implementing NAT is a lot like implementing an IP stack for a router! That's why NAT is virtual always bolted on to an IP stack in the kernel, not implemented in userspace.

#### Sending and receiving packets

So the architecture as I understand it is this:

1. Client originates a packet which goes into the TUNTAP interface
2. Your software gets this packet, encapsulates it in a Websocket message, and sends it off
3. Your Twisted server gets it and does its magic
4. The translated packet goes out from the server through a raw socket

The return path:

1. The reply comes back to your server somehow (perhaps [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap3_man.html))
2. Your code does the reverse magic
3. Your server transits the result back to the client over Websocket
4. Client sees the resulting backet come back through the TUNTAP interface.

I think the easiest way to handle the last step in the forward path and the first step in the return path is a second TUNTAP device: a `tun` interface on the server.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks for the detailed response.  I may not have explained it well.  Basically the client opens a tunnel with itself using two private IPs (10.1.1.2--->10.1.1.1).  The receiving end of the tunnel directs the IP packet through a websocket to the twisted server.  The twisted receiver's data is FROM user1's public IP, however the data itself is an IP packet (most likely from 10.1.1.2).  The server then does NAT and then sends it out.

Comment: I would then listen for an incoming packet, look it up in the NAT table, put the client's private IP back, package it in a websocket and send it back.  The client's TUNTAP would then recieve it (on 10.1.1.1) and send it back to 10.1.1.2.  You're right a second TUNTAP on the server would be easier.  Is this possible?

Comment: Is there a way I could create a TUN bridge over the websocket and\or somehow use the kernel's NAT capabilities as opposed to implementing my own?  Instead of IP over GRE it's IP over WebSocket.  EDIT: I really appreciate the help by the way.

Comment: Absolutely, using the existing NAT capabilities of the kernel on your server is the way to go, I think, to save yourself having to implement a lot of things yourself. The only significant issue I can think of is that the kernel doesn't know that you have multiple independent users each behind their own websocket connection. The way around that is to make sure each user uses a unique private IP (e.g. 10.1.1.2/30 for customer A, 10.1.1.6/30 for customer B) as opposed to each customer reusing the same private IP on the client end. With this the server-side kernel can tell clients apart.

Comment: I just do not see how I can actually do the mapping over this random protocol.  The original client would have to have a route to the tunnel endpoint.  Also what would the server do with the incoming packet.  Please see my edits.

Comment: I think the design of this project is getting beyond the scope of a Stackoverflow question... I understand the 10.x.x.x/30 is private to each client but the reason why it matters to the server is that one of those private IP addresses is the source IP address of the packets which the client sends and which arrive (encapsulated in websockets) at the server. Anyway, when the server gets it, it can shoot it out the `tun` interface at its end. The server's kernel now gets the original packet and must be programmed to NAT it (which is done with `iptables` if it's Linux, otherwise something else).

Comment: Thanks for providing me with a good overview.  I think I got it from here

Comment: Fragmentation is another thing to consider in general for a NAT. Except the first datagram, all other datagrams of a fragmented packets will *not* contain the transport header. So we need to track these fragmented datagrams (which port to send to) using their IP ID field. Also the fragmented datagram may arrive before the datagram containing the transport header, so we have to buffer them. A very good detailed answer by Celada.